# Neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

People often define a neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}^n$ around a point $x$ as $\{z~|~ \|x-z\|_2 \le R\}$ for some $R$. The intuition is the set of points in some Euclidean ball around $x$. This is obviously an extension to the one-dimensional neighborhood $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ for some $x \in \mathbb R$.

I am wondering if we have to use the L2 norm here, or if it is possible to use a different function. Specifically:

1. I think if I use a different norm, for example, $\|z-x\|_1 \le R$, it will also work, as all norms are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it correct?
2. I am not confident if it will work if I use the "fractional norm": $\|x\|_p =(\sum |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ for $0<p<1$. This is not really a norm as it does not satisfy the triangular inequality, but it seems to work because if $\|x\|_p \to 0$ then $\|x\|_2 \to 0$. Is this correct?
3. What about some general distance functions? When can I replace $\|z-x\|_1 \le R$ with $d(z,x) \le R$? And when does it not work?

Comment: As all norms are equivalent, topological properties do not depend on which norm you use.  But, if you choose the discrete metric ($d(x,y) = 1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x) = 0$), every function will become continuous - so topological properties are not preserved.

Comment: I am wondering what kind of distance function can be used. It seems to work if it satisfies that if $d(x,z) \to 0$ then $\|x-z\|_2 \to 0$. Does it sound right?

Comment: @TomBennett Look up equivalent norms and equivalent metrics. In short equivalent norms/metrics induce the same topology. In Euclidean space all norms are equivalent, but not all metrics are equivalent.

Comment: I have never studied topology, but let me check it out. Thanks for the comments.